# Display tags with questions on moderator flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flag-queue

The flag queue displays the title of the question (and the initial text of the flagged post).

It would be good if the tags were displayed too. It would help give context to the question in general, but for "not an answer" flags, it would especially show what knowledge may be needed to tell if in fact it is not an answer.